# My own function does not see locally imported packages why?

Tags: python

I have a collection of functions that I saved as `functions.py` format. These functions need `numpy`, `glob` and other packages. I import the packages e.g., `import glob` and then `import functions`, then when I run a given function `rvs = get_RVdata(path)` I get an error saying glob is not defined.

Why are these standard packages not recognized within my defined functions?

```
def get_RVdata(path):
    '''
    Retrieve from the header of each fits the calculated RV per spectrum
    '''
    rvs = []
    e_rvs = []
    bjd = []
    
    #get ccfs
    CCF_paths = path
    CCF_files = glob.glob(CCF_paths) # contains path
    
    #set variables
    for path in np.sort(CCF_files):
        with fits.open(path) as data:
            rvs.append(data[0].header["ESO QC CCF RV"])
            e_rvs.append(data[0].header["ESO QC CCF RV ERROR"])
            bjd.append(data[0].header["ESO QC BJD"])
    
        return np.array(bjd), np.array(rvs), np.array(e_rvs)
```

The error is this:

```
---> CCF_files = glob.glob(CCF_paths) # contains path
NameError: name 'glob' is not defined
```

Why glob is not seen within my function? I have it loaded outside the function.py. I can solve the problem adding `import glob` from within the function.py but I want to import in my environment.

Comment: Please share the get_ccfs(paths) functions code.

Comment: You could pass `glob.glob`, as a parameter, to `get_ccfs`, if you don't want to import `glob` inside the `functions` module. Although making `functions.py` import what it needs to run is more cleaner.

Comment: Modules have their own scope and they search for references from within that scope. By adding imports in a separate file would not work because the functions will only have access to their own scope.

Comment: Thanks, so modules have their own scopes. But how do I force inheritance? I ended up putting all the imports inside the module and it works fine but if I wanted to import glob and make it be visible within my function from a different module, is there a workaround? a way to make glob be seen without passing it as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is best illustrated with examples:

An example what needs to be in the `functions.py`:

```
import glob

def get_ccfs(paths):
    #get ccfs
    CCF_paths = paths
    CCF_files = glob.glob(CCF_paths) # contains path

    #store CCFS and rv domain

    # this is just a sample return to conform to your original code
    return CCF_files, "some other return"
```

An example of the `other_file_that_calls_functions.py`:

```
from functions import get_ccfs

paths = "./fun*"
a, b = get_ccfs(paths)

print(a)
print(b)
```

An example of a command line call:

```
> python other_file_that_calls_functions.py
['.\\functions.py']
some other return
```